# wxpython accelerators fire even when associated menu item is disabled

Tags: python, menu, wxpython, accelerator

wxPython accelerators seem to fire even when their associated menu items are disabled. Is this a bug? Shouldn't the accelerator keys NOT fire in these situations?

In the short stand-alone example below, if you right click, a popup menu appears with a single menuitem which is DISABLED.  The associated accelerator key **CMD S** can still be triggered, however!?

```
import wx

help = """
If you right click on this window, a popup menu will appear with
a single menuitem which is DISABLED.

The associated accelerator key CMD S can still be triggered, however.

Is this a bug?
Shouldn't the accelerator keys NOT fire when its associated menu item
is disabled?
"""

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Accelerators fire even when menu item is disabled", size=(500,500))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, help, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()

        self.item: wx.Menuself.item = self.popupmenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Do Something (CMD S)")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.DoSomething, self.item)

        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('S'), self.item.GetId() )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

        self.item.Enable(False)  # hmm, accelerator still fires :-(

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.OnRight)

    def OnRight(self, event):
        self.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu)

    def DoSomething(self, event):
        msg = f"Something is being triggered, even though menuitem enabled is {self.item.Enabled}"
        print(msg)
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, msg, "Message", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyForm()
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Perhaps I need to explicitly check in each handler function, whether the ‘menuitem that triggered it’ is enabled or disabled.  This sounds a bit tedious - things should ideally be automatic.  Interestingly, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192551/translateaccelerator-and-disabled-menu-items?rq=1) talks about how these things can indeed be automatic (albiet not wxpython related, and seems specific to windows).

> If an accelerator has the same identifier as a menu item and the menu
>   item is grayed or disabled, the accelerator is disabled and does not
>   generate a WM_COMMAND or WM_SYSCOMMAND message.

I am running Mac OSX under Python 3.7 and wxPython 4.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be correct.
You may have to check or rebuild the accelerator table each time.
You can disable all `Accelerators` temporarily with:

```
self.SetAcceleratorTable(wx.NullAcceleratorTable)
```